# How can I use a computer as a router and send all client traffic through anonymous proxies?

Tags: networking, router, internet, proxy

Is there a way that I can setup a spare box as a router on my network, and route client traffic through a proxy in order to hide my location?

Specifically, I would like internet traffic to/from my [Roku Box](http://www.roku.com/) to be routed via proxy, but there is no proxy support built in to the Roku. So I would like wire my Roku directly my computer's second NIC, and force all traffic through a proxy.

What kind of software and hardware setup will I need? I currently have a spare machine with two NICs and Windows XP. I have tried using the TOR network, and was able to successfully setup internet connection sharing, but was unable to figure out how to force client HTTP traffic to use the proxy.

What type of software setup do I need?

Comment: Giving newbies the keys to anonymity is like a magician showing how he does all his tricks to his audience. Why don't you read up more about networking before expecting magic to be just handed to you?

Comment: I wouldn't call myself a newbie. I know a thing or two about networking. And I've spent a couple of hours on this problem, but wasn't able to come up with a solution. So I'm not expecting anything to be handed to me

Comment: Sounds like you're 90% of the way there. Set the clients' gateway to the xp box that you setup as a proxy.

Comment: Yep, I've been able to share the internet connection but the trouble is forcing the client traffic to use a proxy. I can't figure that piece of it out.

Comment: "...Windows XP." << That's your problem right there. Linux is much more flexible for this type of thing (sorry if I sound like a fanboy).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a transparent proxy.  This is easy to do on Linux, if you start with a guide like [This one](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-setup-transparent-proxy-squid-howto.html)

Then you just have to configure squid on the Linux box to send outgoing connections to your favorite anonymous proxy.