# How can I apply a proxy IP address to all my connections?

Tags: networking, browser, proxy

I live in a building where we share a static IP address. Looks like a roommate got banned from a website where I also have an account, and now I can't visit this website either.

I had to install a proxy plug-in in my browser in order to access this website. However, it only works if I visit this page by the browser, when I try to obtain their services from a specific client software, the connection is refused.

So how can I apply the same IP that the browser uses, to all my connections and softwares? Is there any ways this can be achieved? I'm using Windows 8.0.

Comment: Try [Configuring a proxy through the Local Area Network settings](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/675-how-to-configure-proxy-settings-in-windows-7/).

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.0. Forgot to put it in the question... I will add this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use a computer as a router and send all client traffic through anonymous proxies?](http://superuser.com/questions/127731/how-can-i-use-a-computer-as-a-router-and-send-all-client-traffic-through-anonymo)

Comment: @techie007 Man... I don't uderstand much about networking, and I dont understand nothing about that question, looks complicated... I don't want to use my computer as a router, or provide anonymous traffic to any clientes. I will try An Dorfer solution for now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very easy way to do this, which unfortunately costs money, is to use a commercial VPN service. This will tunnel your traffic from your PC to a different entry point on the Internet, with a different IP address. I have used [www.strongvpn.com](http://www.strongvpn.com) for this purpose and it suited my needs well. You can get an account for less than $5/month. There are many other alternatives.

Comment: That was just what I needed. For now I'm am using a free FVP service, maybe later I might use a commercial one, anyway, it worked just fine. Thanks! :)

Comment: You're right - this looks very promising: http://freevpn.me/